# What is an Invalid Resolution Tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.5, raspberry-pi3

I have a Raspberry Pi camera which has a 'best resolution' of 1080p according to the [specs](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Raspberry-Camera-IR-CUT-Vision-Module/dp/B0768Z87JF)

I have a small script which doesn't achieve anything apart from changing some settings.

```
import picamera
import picamera.array
import numpy
from fractions import Fraction

camera = icamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = 1920*1080
camera.iso = 0
camera.exposure_mode = 'off'
camera.shutter_speed = '10000'

camera.start_preview()
```

When I execute the code I am presented with the following error message followed by the code ending *I have only included the last two lines of the error message*

```
    raise PiCameraValueError("Invalid resolution tuple: %r" % value)
picamera.exc.PiCameraValueError: Invalid resolution tuple: 2073600
```

I have tried changing the resolution to various things such as 1280*720 all the way down to 640*480 with the only change being the last number of the error message.

Unfortunately, this is not a well documented online so I have been unable to find out what's going on.

So what is this error message? What do I need to modify in the code to set the resolution?

Comment: You're passing an integer, the result of multiplying the height and width in pixels, *not* a tuple.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry about that, to save the downvotes I'll delete the question then. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I've undeleted this, as I think it still worth keeping for the answer I wrote. I am, of course, biased here. If you feel strongly about this, delete the question once more and I'll not undelete again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'll leave it open, it is just a simple typographical error ,  instead of * so it's probably going to get closed for that reason anyway.

Comment: @JakeSymons: I didn't *read* it as a typographical error, because someone could conceivably have misread the `"WIDTHxHEIGHT"` string format and accidentally transcribed that to `1920x1080` (no quotes), then to `1920*1080` because multiplication in Python uses `*`.

Comment: @JakeSymons: next, you stated that *Unfortunately, this is not a well documented online*, whereas I found the project you were using to be very well documented, so wanted to link to the documentation in case this was hard to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`camera.resolution` should be set to a *tuple* with two integers:

```
camera.resolution = 1920, 1080
```

Note the comma. From the [`PiCamera.resolution` documentation](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_camera.html#picamera.PiCamera.resolution):

> When set, the property configures the camera so that the next call to these methods will use the new resolution. The resolution can be specified as a  tuple, as a string formatted 'WIDTHxHEIGHT', or as a string containing a commonly recognized display resolution name (e.g. “VGA”, “HD”, “1080p”, etc).

It you feel it helps with readability, you can use parentheses around the tuple values:

```
camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
```

You passed in the result of a multiplication instead, a single integer, and `1920*1080` is 1920 times 1080 is 2073600, the value in the exception message.

You *can* also use a string value, using `x` to separate width and height:

```
camera.resolution = "1920x1080"
```

Perhaps that format led to the error? I can imagine someone connecting `1920x1080` with `1920*1080`, leading to this confusion.

The strings `"FHD"` and `"1080p"` would also be correct, as [FHD 1080p cameras use that exact resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution#1920_%C3%97_1080_(FHD)).